# Casting C# char to int ignores Endianness

Tags: c#, unicode, endianness, utf-16

According to https://unicode-table.com/en/1E9E/ the 'ẞ' (sharp S) has a

UTF-16 little-endian decimal value = 40478

UTF-16 big-endian decimal value = 7838

However, when running this snippet of code, I get an un-understandable behavior. Why is this happening?

```
Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.IsLittleEndian); // prints True
char c = 'ẞ';
Console.WriteLine((int)c); // prints 7838. For little-endian it should print 40478.
```

Comment: A character is a code-point, which is an integer value. That's what you're getting. Endianness is about representation of the bytes that comprise the value. Casting has nothing to do with representation. If endianness matters to you, you need to use `BitConverter` or something like that and look at the bytes.

Comment: The character `ẞ` is Unicode codepoint U+1E9E, whose decimal value is 7838. In UTF-16, that codepoint is encoded as bytes `1E 9E` or `9E 1E` depending on endian, but the codepoint value doesn't change due to endian.